# How to change grid row background color

Tags: magento-2.1

How can I change grid row background color? For example in magento 1 it can be done in some grid class with method `getRowClass` returning some css class name like this:

```
public function getRowClass(Varien_Object $row)
{
   return 'some-css-class';
}
```

I just wonder how can I achieve this in magento 2?

Regards,